os/exec: Cannot execute command with argument that has multiple values
I'm trying to execute openssl command using exec.Command:
opensssl x509 -text -noout -certopt=ca_default,no_validity,no_serial,no_subject,no_extensions,no_signame <<< [CERT] 
I tried to do it like this
func (c *Certificate) GetSignature() (string, error) {
    // getSignatureCommand = "x509 -text -noout -certopt=ca_default,no_validity,no_serial,no_subject,no_extensions,no_signame"
    argsSlice := strings.Split(getSignatureCommand, " ")

    stderr := &bytes.Buffer{}
    stdout := &bytes.Buffer{}

    // openSSLCommand = "openssl"
    cmd := exec.Command(openSSLCommand, argsSlice...)
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(c.cert)
    cmd.Stderr = stderr
    cmd.Stdout = stdout
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil || stderr.Len() > 0 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to execute command: %v: %v", err, stderr.String())
    }

    // remove last \n
    signature := stdout.String()
    signature = strings.TrimRight(signature, "\n")

    return signature, nil
}

I also tried changing the getSignatureCommand to
x509 -text -noout -certopt ca_default,no_validity,no_serial,no_subject,no_extensions,no_signame
And to
x509 -text -noout -certopt ca_default -certopt no_validity -certopt no_serial -certopt no_subject -certopt no_extensions -certopt no_signame 
All fail with error: failed to execute command: exit status 1: x509: Use -help for summary.
What am I doing wrong?
I exect something like this:
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Signature Value:
6d:94:92:e0:e4:a4:f4:65:aa:e3:cc:1b:9f:2a:01:b0:20:cf:
67:5a:58:cf:aa:d9:99:08:07:91:9a:0b:b6:2b:52:9d:f0:e5:
0d:50:cb:66:8c:a6:93:21:36:11:c7:30:98:45:65:43:e1:54:
a5:22:0bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1e:05:
0e:e3:10:01:73:06:5b:98:f5:e8:6d:73:a5:65:8d:3d:48:b0:
21:4a:30:9f:7c:7d:99:d0:e7:c1:cc:22:fa:c4:fc:9c:48:3f:
ff:83:72:98:d0:33:3b:05:69:84:fd:7b:bc:b8:e6:44:96:cf:
58:27:4c:c3:d1:9d:c1:f1:02:f8:3c:11:92:fe:fa:c1:ff:48:
cf:a8:e9:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:9b:b0:4f:c2:ca:
28:5b:13:c2:1d:c9:79:7a:71:4c:9c:4a:f5:26:60:6d:75:3f:
00:31:57:8f:00:99:ca:93:52:5d:fc:dd:71:76:1b:22:61:4b:
5f:29:f6:77:fd:f0:e5:20:dc:fd:e1:d5:d2:05:a3:3f:96:2c:
d9:cc:d9:87:9c:7b:16:c8:4f:2c:2e:b6:dd:bd:e5:9b:d7:97:
c5:b0:31:19:69:a7:f8:f9:3e:b2:0b:3d:b0:13:68:a1:1d:ee:
e3:86:60:77


You shouldn't conflate openssl producing output on stderr with the command failing. The conditional should solely check err returned by cmd.Run().
